# foreach loop C# Windows Forms, same button click event

Tags: c#, windows, forms, foreach

```
private void opc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //NOTE: buttons 13-16 share same click event

    // needs for each loop 
    button13.Enabled = false;
    button14.Enabled = false;
    button15.Enabled = false;
    button16.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Please add more information on what you're asking exactly. Do you want one button to disable all of them? Do you want all buttons to disable only themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
private void opc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 13; i <= 16; i++)
    {
        Control[] buttons = this.Controls.Find(String.Format("button{0}", i), false);
        if (buttons.Length > 0)
        {
            Button btn = (buttons[0] as Button);
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            btn.Enabled = true; // or false
        }
    }
}


void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See code below :

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button13.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.button14.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.button15.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.button16.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            string name = button.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the assignmens into a loop? With statically defined names for the buttons that is not possible AFAIK. You should put the buttons into an array or collection in the first place:

```
Button[] button = new Button[numberOfButtons];
for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++)
{
    button[i] = new Button();
    button[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(WhateverYouLike);
    // ... some other property assignments, probably also rule-based
}

// ... and at a later time:

for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++) button[i].Enabled = false;
```